# findOrCreate is not finding data in my db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I created a remote method to make multiple queries to my DB where I want to findOrCreate up to 12 users models at one time. In the loopback explorer I am passing this array, `["player0", "player1", "player2"]` to my function which I know are all already in my DB. However, the problem I am running into is that I am returned a status of 200 and an array of null values. If I pass names that are not in the DB I am returned an object for each name with all of the default values as expect.
So my question is what is wrong with the find portion of my code?

I have tried adding the where clause to my findOrCreate and its still returning an array of null.

UPDATE: HERE IS THE WHOLE METHOD

````
function getPlayerStats(names) {
  console.log('names: ', names);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { Player } = app.models;
    const playerData = names.map(name => {
      console.log('single name: ', name);
      const defaultSkill = 1500;
      return Player.findOrCreate(
        { where: { name: name } },
        {
          name: name,
          careerSkill: defaultSkill,
          careerHighestSkill: defaultSkill,
          careerWins: 0,
          careerLosses: 0,
          careerPercent: 0,
          careerBestLeader: 'none',
          careerAllLeader: ['none'],
          highestCareerSkill: defaultSkill,
          careerSeasonWins: 0,
          careerSeasonLosses: 0,
          careerSeasonPercent: 0       
    }
      );
    });
    Promise.all(playerData)
      .then(results => resolve(results))
      .catch(err => reject(new Error('could not return results')));
  });
}

module.exports = { getPlayerStats };```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add `return` before `Player.findOrCreate({name: name},`
`Player.findOrCreate({ where: { name: name } },...` is proper version of filter.
Also, you can omit that callback `(err) => {` because you have `catch` block

Whole function could look like that:
`player.js`

```
   Player.getPlayerStats = function (names, cb) {

        const playerPromises = names.map(name => {
            const defaultSkill = 1500;
            return Player.findOrCreate({ where: { name: name } }, {
                "name": name,
                "careerSkill": defaultSkill,
                "careerHighestSkill": defaultSkill,
                "careerWins": 0,
                "careerLosses": 0,
                "careerPercent": 0,
                "careerBestLeader": "none",
                "careerAllLeader": ["none"],
                "highestCareerSkill": defaultSkill,
                "careerSeasonWins": 0,
                "careerSeasonLosses": 0,
                "careerSeasonPercent": 0
            })
        })


        Promise.all(playerPromises)
            .then(players => cb(null, players))
            .catch(err => cb(new Error('could not return results'), null))
    }
```

Comment: Ok this is some progress. I added in the `return` before `Player.findOrCreate({name: name},` added in the `where` clause and removed the `(err) => {`

Any new names in the array all get created in the DB however, the response body only ever returns the first found or created player. What else am I missing to return all of the players data that I passed to the function.

Comment: Ok check my edit and how your remoteMethod declaration looks like?

Comment: ok I have updated the original post to include the whole method

Comment: ok and how you register this method? You should have something like Player.remoteMethod(...

Comment: Correct. I defined the Player.remoteMethod in `/models/Player.js` 
Actually the whole thing is working now thank you! Just had to add the `return` to the `Player.findOrCreate...`